# CSS Grid, have an image fill height of grid item?

Tags: css, css-grid

I want to create an image grid with one large image and two smaller ones to the right of the large one, like so; [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BW8eg.jpg):
For some reason, the images won't fill the entire height of my grid items. I've found some suggestions involving setting "object-fit: cover;" on the grid items containing images but it doesn't work.

HTML:

```
<div class="proj-grid">
    <div class="featured"><img src="images/grid_test.png" alt=""></div>
    <div class="mini1"><img src="images/grid_test.png" alt=""></div>
    <div class="mini2"><img src="images/grid_test.png" alt=""></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.proj-grid {
  display: grid;

  grid-template-areas:
    "featured featured mini1"
    "featured featured mini2";

  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 1rem;
}
.featured {
  grid-area: featured;
}

.mini1 {
  grid-area: mini1;
}

.mini2 {
  grid-area: mini2;
}
```

What am I missing here?
Thanks!

Comment: Try this `.featured > img, .mini1 > img, .mini2 > img  {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 object-fit: cover;
}`

[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/Talavoock/4vedynqz/24/)

Comment: Did you try `vertical-align: bottom` on your `img` elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is either the height of your image or (if your image's size is appropriately calculated) because you didn't set the image to `display: block;`.

Here is a working example using `overflow: hidden;` on the larger image to keep aspect ratio.

```css
.proj-grid {
  display: grid;

  grid-template-areas:
    "featured featured mini1"
    "featured featured mini2";

  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 1rem;
}

.featured {
  grid-area: featured;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.mini1 {
  grid-area: mini1;
}

.mini2 {
  grid-area: mini2;
}

img {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="proj-grid">
    <div class="featured"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x150" alt=""></div>
    <div class="mini1"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x150" alt=""></div>
    <div class="mini2"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x150" alt=""></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This solved it, thanks! :-)

Comment: No problem, glad I could help